# Зачем нужен атрибут scope и его значения "col" и "row"?

Tags: html, вёрстка, таблицы

Зачем они нужны если при создании таблицы всё работает и без них?

Comment: [A new topic for this article is the scope attribute, which can be added to the <th> element to **tell screenreaders exactly what cells the header is a header for** — is it a header for the row it is in, or the column, for example?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Advanced#The_scope_attribute)

Comment: То есть по сути это является важным только для программ экранного доступа так? Всегда ли нужно использовать этот атрибут?
P.S. можно по русски?

Comment: @JustLearn воспользуйтесь переключением языка на MDN (русский точно есть там)

Comment: @Grundy То есть по сути это является важным только для программ экранного доступа так? Всегда ли нужно использовать этот атрибут?

Comment: @VladSpirin я сейчас почитал, что такое MDN в интернете. Мне не очень подходит, мне удобней обучаться по книгам, и если возникают вопросы, то заходить и спрашивать здесь.

Comment: @JustLearn, как ты написал в вопросе, с функциональной точки зрения, они ни на что не влияют, поэтому стоит их использовать или нет нужно определять из того, на сколько важна поддержка [accessibility](https://www.w3.org/WAI/fundamentals/accessibility-intro/)

Comment: Всё спасибо, вопрос решён.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Атрибут `scope` связывает между собой ячейки с заголовком и обычные ячейки. По своему действию напоминает атрибут `headers`, но используется для простых таблиц.

Атрибут предназначен для экранных ридеров, вроде речевых браузеров, в обычных браузерах результат добавления `scope` никак не заметен.

Синтаксис:

```
<td scope="col | row | colgroup | rowgroup"></td>
```

В [комментарии @Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/914566/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82-scope-%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-col-%d0%b8-row/914590#comment1505882_914566) дал много [информации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Advanced#The_scope_attribute), пройдя по ссылкам, можно найти остальное.

Comment: Всё спасибо, вопрос решён.